# grep with regular expressions won't see files

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I am constantly having these problems with grep. It is as if sometimes it just stops working for no apparent reason.
I have a number of files in a directory, say:
car1, car2, car3..., car9.txt

When I type egrep "blabla" car[0-9][0-9]*.txt I get: "No such file or directory"
The same thing happens with the "+" sign.

Why am I not seeing the single digit files here?

Comment: What happens if you do `ls car[0-9][0-9]*.txt` ?

Comment: the same thing. No files are found :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell applies [wildcard expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) to the command line, not regular expressions. See also `man 7 glob` for more details.

Thus, `*` means "zero or more (any) characters" but does **not** mean "zero or more of the *previous* entity" and hence does not apply to `[0-9]`, so what you're searching for is:

```
"car" [any of 0-9] [any of 0-9] (zero or more of any chars) ".txt"
```

which will not find any single-digit file names.

To find single-digit files, use:

```
egrep "blabla" car[0-9].txt
```

To find single-digit files or double-digit, use:

```
egrep "blabla" car[0-9].txt car[0-9][0-9].txt
```

or try the following:

```
egrep "blabla" car[0-9]*.txt
```

which will may capture more than just `car [any digits] .txt` but it is an approximation that may work in this case, depending on the other contents of your directory.

Note that `grep` applies regular expression matching to *its* parameter, in this case `"blabla"` but that happens after shell processing has happened.